# Share image and text to messages/mail iOS

Tags: ios, image, text, sendmail, sendmessage

i want to send image and text to messages and mail on iOS.

I try to do it with `UIActivityViewController`, but

1. The images change "minimum" size, even i change to size 8x8 px (the image was big with hudge squares).
2. Image was always sharing before text, even i send a sequence like "text, image, text, image" it always return - "image, image, text, text".

It is the other way to do that properly?

It is possible to that on `MFMessageComposeViewController` or in `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Thanks for any help.